# MySQL Variable Assignment via Procedure Not Working Correctly

Tags: mysql, loops, variables, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

In the code below, I'm trying go through the results of `endDateTable` row by row, comparing the current row's `endDate` to the previous row's `endDate`. If there has been any change since the previous, we increment `@revisionNum`. However, upon populating the new table, all of the `@revisionNum` entries are `0`. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I'm using prepared statements in this manner since doing a straightforward `SELECT` into a variable gives a syntax error due to the `LIMIT` clause not allowing a variable in our version of MySQL.

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE _currentEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT now();
 DECLARE _priorEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT now();

 SET @ResultsCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mainTable);

 SET @j = 0;
    WHILE @j < @ResultsCount DO

        SET @revisionNum = 0;

        /*CURRENT END DATE*/
        SET @appResultQueryCurrent = CONCAT('
            SELECT 
                end_date
            INTO _currentEndDate
            FROM endDateTable 
            LIMIT ', @j, ', 1'
        );      

        PREPARE currentQueryStmt FROM @appResultQueryCurrent;
        EXECUTE currentQueryStmt;

        /*PREVIOUS END DATE*/
        SET @appResultQueryPrior = CONCAT('
            SELECT
                end_date
            INTO _priorAppEndDate
            FROM endDateTable
            LIMIT ', IF(@j = 0, 0, @j - 1), ', 1'
        );

        PREPARE priorQueryStmt FROM @appResultQueryPrior;
        EXECUTE priorQueryStmt; 

        SET @revisionNum = IF(
                @j = 0 OR (_currentEndDate = _priorEndDate),
                @revisionNum,
                IF(
                    _currentEndDate != _priorEndDate,
                    @revisionNum + 1,
                    @revisionNum
                )
            );

        INSERT INTO finalTable (RevisionNum)
        SELECT 
            @revisionNum AS RevisionNum 
        FROM endDateTable;

    SET @j = @j +1;

 END WHILE;

END $$
```

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` can produce unpredictable results.

Comment: Why are you doing a separate query for each row, instead of a cursor?

Comment: The results in `endDateTable` are already ordered correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Database tables don't have any inherent ordering, you have to use `ORDER BY` to specify what order a particular query should use.

Comment: There is an outer loop that is not pictured here, which selects and orders the results before populating the `endDateTable`.

Comment: The order that you insert into the table is not remembered.

Comment: Give them an auto-increment ID and use `ORDER BY id` to process them in the same order that they were inserted.

Comment: During the outer loop, only a small batch of results goes into the table each time, which is already ordered and has an auto incremented ID.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you use `LIMIT @j, 1` you need to put `ORDER BY id` before it.

Comment: I concur with all of the points raised by Barmar. In addtion, don't process Row By Agonizing Row executing dynamic sql to fetch individual rows, if the goal is to loop through and process every row in the table, use a CURSOR loop. Also, use procedure variables rather than user-defined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, incrementing the variable in the select query.

You also need an `ORDER BY` criteria to specify how to order the rows when comparing one row to the previous row.

```
INSERT INTO finalTable (RevisionNum, otherColumn)
SELECT revision, otherColumn
FROM (
    SELECT IF(end_date = @prev_end_date, @revision, @revision := @revision + 1) AS revision,
            @prev_end_date := end_date,
            otherColumn
    FROM endDateTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_end_date := NULL, @revision := -1) AS vars
    ORDER BY id) AS x
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xztpcRZp9kqvygdFvmBWJu/0)

Comment: can you show this insert working with multiple columns?

Comment: What do you mean? LIke a product column, and you want to go back to 0 whenever the product changes?

Comment: I just mean can you show an example where we insert the `revisionNum` into `finalTable` along with an additional column from the `endDateTable`?

Comment: I've added another column

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the logic here.

Comment: `@prev_end_date` holds the date from the previous line. When `end_date` changes, we assign `@revision := @revision + 1`, so it increments the revision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197888/discussion-between-g-d-and-barmar).

Comment: I tried to open a chat discussion......nonetheless, i'll write the comment here: this is working, however this does not account for a NULL `end_date`. many of the `end_date` fields will be NULL. In this scenario, a NULL `end_date`, to another NULL `end_date` results in a revision increment. additionally, all revision numbers will start at 0.

Comment: You can use the null-safe equality operator `<=>` to deal with null end dates.

Comment: Great, However - now what I'm finding is that when it goes to `endDateTable` and starts the comparison, if the first row has a NULL `end_date` then it gets assigned `0`, however if the first row has a non NULL `end_date` it gets assigned `1`. The incrementing is working correctly though, but all entries in the final table should start with '0'

Comment: I guess you'll need another variable that says whether this is the first row, so you can handle that specially.

Comment: It doesn't seem dependent on the first row. For instance, If my `endDateTable` has only two rows, the first of which has a NULL `end_date`, it is getting assigned `0`. However, if my `endDateTable` has only two rows, the first of which has a NON NULL `end_date`, it is getting assigned `1`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. We initialize `@revision` to `-1`. If the first row has a non-null end date, it should increment to `0`, since it's not the same as `@revision`.

Comment: Last Question: is there a reason you used `CROSS JOIN` instead of `JOIN`? MySQL seems to produce the same results in this scenario when using either.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` means that you're creating a cross-product rather than specifying a relationship between the tables. MySQL allows you to omit the `ON` clause in a normal `JOIN`, but this makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The offset value in the `LIMIT` clause is tenuous without an `ORDER BY`.

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL is free to return results in any sequence.

There is no guarantee that `LIMIT 41,1` will return the row before `LIMIT 42,1`, or that it won't return the exact same row as `LIMIT 13,1` did.

(A table in a relational database represents an unordered set of tuples, there is no guaranteed "order" or rows in a table.)

But just adding `ORDER BY` to the queries isn't enough to fix the Rube-Goldberg-esque rigmarole.

In the code shown, it looks like each time through the loop, we're inserting a copy of `endDateTable` into `finalTable`. If that's 1,000 rows in endDateTable, we're going to get 1,000,000 rows (1,000 x 1,000) inserted into finalTable. Not at all clear why we need so many copies.

Given the code shown, it's not clear what the objective is. Looks like we are conditionally incrementing revisionNum, the end result of which is the highest revision num. Just guessing here.

If there is some kind of requirement to do this in a LOOP construct, within a procedure, I'd think we'd do a cursor loop. And we can use procedure variables vs user-defined variables.

Something along these lines:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE ld_current_end_date  DATETIME;
  DECLARE ld_prior_end_date    DATETIME;
  DECLARE li_done              INT;
  DECLARE li_revision_num      INT;
  DECLARE lcsr_end_date CURSOR FOR SELECT t.end_date FROM `endDateTable` t ORDER BY NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET li_done = TRUE;
  SET li_done = FALSE;
  SET li_revision_num = 0;
  OPEN lcsr_end_date;
  FETCH lcsr_end_date INTO ld_current_end_date;
  SET ld_prior_end_date = ld_current_end_date;
  WHILE NOT li_done DO
    SET li_revision_num = li_revision_num + IF( ld_current_end_date <=> ld_prior_end_date ,0,1);
    SET ld_prior_end_date := ld_current_end_date;
    FETCH lcsr_end_date INTO ld_current_end_date;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE lcsr_end_date;
  INSERT INTO `finalTable` (revisionnum) VALUES (li_revision_num);
END $$
```

Note the "order by" clause on the SELECT, its not clear what the rows should be ordered on, so we're using a literal as a placeholder.

As the end result, we insert a single row into `finalTable`.

Again, it's not clear what the code in the question is supposed to achieve, but doing a cursor loop across ordered rows would be much more efficient than a bazillion dynamic SQL executions fetching individual rows.

Comment: Shouldn't the `FETCH` and `INSERT` be in the loop?

Comment: Yes, there is a `FETCH` in the loop. There's an initial fetch before the loop, so we  can handle the special case of the first row. I was confused by the `INSERT`, in the OP code, it's doing an `INSERT ... SELECT` of every row in endDateTable, and doing that for every row. That just doesn't look right to me. It looks to me like the purpose is just to get the highest revision number, but I'm just guessing. Yes, we could do an `INSERT` inside the loop if we want multiple rows in finalTable. Then again, I'm not even clear why we need a loop at all, why not just do this in a single SQL statement?

Comment: The original code does an insert after every fetch, conditionally incrementing `@revisionNum` first.

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose is to get a row for each row in `endDateTable`, and the values of the `RevisionNum` change in each row.

Comment: OP code does an insert after every fetch, it does an `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM endDateTable` for every fetch. Inserts *n* copies of *n* rows. Yes, we can move that `INSERT`  inside the loop, so it gets performed once for each row fetched.

Comment: My understanding of the problem, the big rocks OP needs to get over: 1) results from SELECT are not ordered without ORDER BY 2) don't process Row By Agonizing Row generating and executing dynamic SQL to fetch individual rows, 3) if we need to loop through each row in a table, use a CURSOR loop. 4) within a procedure, use procedure variables rather than user-defined variables, 5) ...

Comment: I didn't even notice that it has `FROM endDateTable` in the `INSERT`. That's weird and probably wrong.

Comment: There can be multiple rows in `endDateTable`. Each set in `endDateTable` can have either NULL or NON NULL values for the `end_date` field. The goal is to compare each row in `endDateTable` to the previous and see if there has been a change. If there has been a change increment the revision number. Revision numbers are zero based.